# What is causing "Can't Ship To" error message in Amazon Pay?

Tags: amazon-pay

Amazon Pay "Can't Ship To" error message.

Upon clicking the Amazon Pay button to checkout, users will get an error message from the Amazon Pay popup that says, "Shopcraftables can't ship to WA". So, it's saying "[Amazon Store Name] can't ship to [user's shipping address state].

I've tried multiple ship-to addresses with different states, always the same message, only the state abbreviation changes.

BigCommerce says it's not their issue.

I can't find any settings in Seller Central or Amazon Pay's setup that even remotely looks like it could affect / cause this issue.
[Error Message from Amazon Pay popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8fRk.png)

Answer (score 1):

We figured out the issue. The problem was neither in the Amazon Pay config nor the Big Commerce config. We're using ShippingHQ with BigCommerce, and the fallback methods must be set - and at some point, they had been switched to only Tennessee.